# How to go to a Directory in cmd/java

Tags: java, cmd

In Java, I wrote a simple program which catches a file and gives that file's path to `cmd` to do something.

If java gave me a path: `C:/Users/Asus Fx/Desktop`, *(note the space between Asus and Fx)*, I'd need to give the `cmd` this directory. However it won't find anything because I'd need to use `%20` between `Asus` and `Fx` to make it like this: `file:///C:/Users/Asus%20Fx/Desktop`.

When I give this directory to `cmd`, it doesn't recognize it because it turns becomes `C:/Users/Asus0Fx/Desktop`, *it's deleting the `%20` and replacing it with a `0`.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You should never have to write `%20` explicitly.  Why do you need a URL at all?  What does “give this directory to cmd” mean?  Are you using ProcessBuilder?  Does “make getBytes” refer to the String.getBytes method?  Including some of the code in your question would help considerably.

Comment: Can you provide some details (i.e. code) as to what you have done so far and where you think the problem is?
Also, can you provide some sample data, what your expected results are along with the actual results you are getting?
Are there any error messages? If so, can you include them?

Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a path which contains one or more white-spaces I believe you need to enclose that command line parameter argument within quotation marks:

```
"C:/Users/Asus Fx/Desktop"
```

This is a usual criteria for Command Line applications since a white-space could signify the start of a new command line argument.

Comment: I have done this but It didin't work at all, now I'm doing this for the second time and It worked correctly :|